# Javascript insert text / smily in textarea by id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to present a list of possible smilys, when the user clicks on them the specific mark :P or :+ for example should be posted in the text area after or between the text he or she typed allready. I cant make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Textarea:

```
<textarea id="SendMessageForm" cols=1 rows=1 oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"' type="text" wrap="virtual" data-token="<?php echo $token; ?>" data-messageto="<?php echo $LoadMessageFromUser; ?>" class="form-control hass-message-input" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
```

Sample for the smilys and the call to the function

```
<img src="emoticons/clown.gif" alt="Emoticon" onClick="insertEmoticon(':+');" />
<img src="emoticons/puh2.gif" alt="Emoticon" onClick="insertEmoticon(':P');" />
```

Javascript to make this happen

```
function insertEmoticon(smiley){ 
    var myField = document.getElementById(SendMessageForm); 
        if (document.selection) {
            myField.focus();
            var sel  = document.selection.createRange();
            if (sel.text == "") { 
                
                sel.text += smiley;
                myField.focus();
            } else { 
                
                sel.text = smiley;
            }
        } else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos    = myField.selectionStart;
            var endPos      = myField.selectionEnd;
            if (startPos == endPos) { 
                
            } else { 
                var str = myField.value.substring(startPos, endPos); 
            }
            var myVal   = smiley;
            myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myVal + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
        } else {
            myField.value += smiley;
        }}
```

Any help is welcome (sorry for my language)

Comment: No error? Fix `document.getElementById(SendMessageForm);` to `document.getElementById('SendMessageForm');` Use quotation.

Comment: So easy.. Thanks for your reaction that worked ! Use caution you say, with that you mean sanitize input etc ?

Comment: Sorry, misread. Quotation, you mean put between 'id'. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you haven't surrounded the value passed into `getElementById` with quotes.

---

To fix this, just use the code below.

```js
document.getElementById("SendMessageForm");
```

The difference is that this code has `SendMessageForm` surrounded by quotes, unlike your code.

If you don't surround the value with quotes, then JavaScript will start looking for a variable called `SendMessageForm`, and use that value.

By surrounding it by quotes, you are saying that you want to search for `SendMessageForm` explicity.

---

In conclusion, you need to surround `SendMessageForm` with quotes to signify that it isn't a variable, but a `string`.